# Creating Database for ios

Tags: python, ios, database

I'm creating an app in which database will be updated via server, or it should be replaced by new one. Can you give me some tips, should I use CoreData or SqlLite. And how it should be updated. I'm using python for parsing data, and then I want to create DB.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not very specific, but if you are not sure what you really need, stay away from CoreData. Start with SQLite and maybe use a light wrapper on top of it. I personally use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

There are quite a few examples in FMDB on how to select, insert, update etc.  Quick example select from the [Executing Queries](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#executing-queries) section of the readme:

```
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/tmp/tmp.db"];

FMResultSet *s = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM myTable"];
while ([s next]) {
    //retrieve values for each record
}
```